# search for string recursively and replace the string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to find a specific string in the Windows PATH recursively and replace the string with another string:

Task # 1

I identified(with help) on how to identify the path of available string using the below script.

```
findstr /s /i /m /c:"topaz3258" H:\MKS\build\host\dev\*.* > H:\topaz3258\result.txt
```

Task # 2

Now I need your assistance to update "topaz3258" with "topaz103258" in all the above path identified for the string. The file type is "*.ini" and "*.cmd" files.

Note: Powershell is restricted in the organization, so I have to use Batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With powershell scripts you can do a regex replacement within a file pretty easy. I just pulled an example from something I had already, this should probably work in general. but this is just to do one file

(gc *"input filename"* -raw) -replace 'topaz3258', 'topaz103258' | Out-File -encoding ASCII *"output filename"*

You can iterate over files pretty easily though
https://theitbros.com/powershell-script-for-loop-through-files-and-folders/

edit, im just writing this freehand but it might look something like

```
$files = Get-ChildItem H:\MKS\build\host\dev\ -Recurse *.*

foreach ($f in $files){

(gc $f.FullName -raw) -replace 'topaz3258', 'topaz103258' | Out-File -encoding ASCII $f.FullName

}
```

if you dont want to do it in-place you can specify a different output path or else just copy the folder tree before operating on it. Depends on what you need exactly. star dot star is a very wide net to cast btw, you might want to filter by text files only or something

---

### If you dont have powershell

I quickly put this together from other answers (Also edited). It will no longer make a new file, it writes directly into the original file. This is dangerous, you cant go back. There is no undo so make a temporary backup somehow. The script will preserve blank lines. It will not respect word boundaries so for example

red blue reddit  (red -> green)  green blue greendit

```
@echo off
SET FIND_STR=topaz3258
SET REPL_STR=topaz103258
SET ROOT_DIR=H:\MKS\build\host\dev\


for /R "%ROOT_DIR%" %%a in (*.txt) do (
    :: say the filename
    echo %%a

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%a" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%%a"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:*]=!"
        if defined line set "line=!line:%FIND_STR%=%REPL_STR%!"
        >>"%%a" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks, but the *.ini file is not getting updated and the result is only taking the final line from the ini file and placing it under the result

Comment: ok true, the >> was needed instead of > but I also completely changed the script to also preserve blank lines and directly write the results into the original file. There are no temporary files now so please do make a complete backup of the files you are working on, at least until you know the script is working for you, it has the power to completely erase files but I did test it on my system

Comment: No problem, sorry it took so long, I thought Id get it with powershell real quick but I think in the end I learned something too. If you think my answer is helpful please accept it, Im trying to grind out my initial reputation so I can vote on other peoples answers